# In the Star Trek: Voyager episode "Resolutions," what was it about the planet that afforded them protection from the virus?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

Janeway and Chakotay are left on a planet due to the planet affording them protection from a virus they had contracted from some bugs that lived on the planet.

What about this planet protected them from the virus?

Answer (score 2):

This is never explained in detail. From the [Star Trek Memory Alpha Wiki](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Resolutions_%28episode%29):

> It appears that the only way the two officers can avoid developing the
>   deadly symptoms is to remain on the planet, where an unknown element
>   is able to protect them for the disease's effects.

Ultimately a cure/serum is provided by the Vidiians.